# b->next->next gives error in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

These 2 lines give error - dereferencing pointer to incompatible types.

`while(b->next!=NULL ||b->next->next!=NULL)`

`b=b->next->next;`

**Full Code Below**

```
typedef struct NODE
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

void middle(node **head)
{
    struct NODE *a = *head;
    struct NODE *b = *head;

    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        printf("List Empty\n");
        return;
    }
    while(b->next!=NULL ||b->next->next!=NULL)
    {
        a=a->next;
        b=b->next->next;
    }
    printf("MID = %d\n", a->data);
}


 void find_len(node *head, int n)
{
    node *temp = head;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Length = %d\n", n);
        return;
    }
    else
        find_len(temp->next, ++n);
}
```

**Function Call in main()**

```
middle(&head);
```

Comment: `struct node` isn't defined anywhere so the compiler doesn't know what it is.

Comment: @melpomene i have used `typedef`

Comment: You have `struct NODE` and `node`, but no `struct node`.

Comment: And I believe you have `head` declared as global and then you have a function argument named head as well. This is bad and confusing.

Comment: @TonyTannous head is not global

Comment: @melpomene sorry i didn't get you. what's wrong in the program?

Comment: @AnkushKapoor See my first comment.

Comment: That edit made no difference. You used `typedef`, so `node` and `struct NODE` are the same type. But `struct node` still doesn't exist.

Comment: @melpomene i have changed the code(see the code above). But it still gives the same error

Comment: `node` is not the same as `struct node` is not the same as `struct NODE`.

Comment: @melpomene i have added another function `find_len`. It works correctly and there are several other functions in which i have used `node *temp`. I can't get why is it not working in `middle` function

Comment: Please follow these guidelines so you can get better answers faster! [mcve]

Comment: The call `find_len(temp->next, ++n)` is a type error. Your compiler should be complaining about that. The type error is that `find_len` takes a `node *` but you're giving it a `struct node *`.

Comment: @melpomene i got the error. Error is in line 4 `struct node *next;` this should have been `struct NODE *next;`. My mistake :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the declaration of `struct NODE`, the reference to `struct node` is undefined. Write like this:

```
typedef struct NODE {
    int data;
    struct NODE *next;
} node;
```

This loop condition is incorrect:

> ```
> while (b->next!=NULL || b->next->next!=NULL)
> ```

You only want to advance the loop when both terms are not null:

```
while (b->next != NULL && b->next->next != NULL)
```

Lastly,
the `*head==NULL` condition will never be true.
This is because you cannot have a pointer to `NULL`.
So in case of an empty list, `head` itself will be `NULL`.
So you need to rewrite the beginning of the function a bit,
carefully avoiding null pointer dereferences, for example:

```
node *a, *b;

if (head == NULL)
{
    puts("List Empty");
    return;
}

a = b = *head;
```

I also changed `printf` to `puts`.
When you don't need to format the string,
and just want to print with a trailing newline, `puts` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the type problems, you're using an ||.  That means that it will not short circuit when the first condition is false.  In other words, even if `b->next` is equal to null, execution will continue and evaluate `b->next->next`, which will clearly lead to bad things if `b->next` was NULL already.

If you change your || to and &&, it will short circuit.